# Process Builder won't Recognize User Currency ISO

Tags: process-builder

I created a process builder which is checking if the Owner is a USD or CAD currency iso code:

```
AND(ISNEW()=False,
    ISPICKVAL([Lead].CurrencyIsoCode,"CAD"),
    OR(
        And(
            LEFT([Lead].OwnerId ,3)="00G",
            NOT(LEFT([Lead].OwnerId,15) ="00GC0000002JZpt")
        ),
        AND(
            LEFT([Lead].OwnerId ,3)="005",
            ISPICKVAL([Lead].Owner:User.CurrencyIsoCode,"USD")
        )
    )
)
```

When the process builder runs though I receive the following error:

> The flow failed to access the value for
>   myVariable_current.Owner:User.CurrencyIsoCode because it hasn't been
>   set or assigned.

But the owner of the record is my user account which has a USD currency code. Could anyone narrow this down to what's happening?

Comment: as possible workaround - add custom formula field to Lead: `Owner_Currency__c` and define using the polymorphic formula expression. Don't forget to take into account that Leads can be owned by queues and they wont have a currency. Then use Process builder to ref this new formula field

Comment: The first and statement in the or accounts for that... it appears the process builder just doesn't have access to the Currency Code of the owner for some reason.

Comment: Hence why I suggested the workaround as ProcessBuilder will definitely have access to fields on the object

Comment: Then why is it even a selection in the standard criteria too. I just don't understand if it doesn't have "access" to it why its a default relationship

Comment: You shouldn't have to make custom fields for things that are already existing thats how redundancy is created in systems